# jQuery IE7 / IE8: Prevent change event triggering on Enter

Tags: jquery

Here is sample code:

http://jsfiddle.net/BSjGX/1/

```
<input id="testing" />

$('#testing')
    .keydown(function(e){
        if(e.keyCode==13) {return false;}
    })
    .change(function(){
        $('body').append('<br />changed');
    });
```

How do you ppl doing it in IE7 / IE8 etc?

Thanks ;)

Comment: Not exactly sure what you want to do. Do you want to stop the Enter key from doing something or stop the "change" from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is, that the fact that it's changed has already occurred before your code is used.

So you can eat the change, but then on blur, it won't react that it's changed.  Try this:

```
$('#testing')
    .change(function(e){
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
        $('body').append('<br />changed');
    });
```

I think you'll see what I mean.  I think to do what you want, you might need to have your own variable, and track changes.

Comment: Oh sorry mate. Didn't notice that it's not undefined in Internet Explorer. Why so? O_o Very interesting. I guess i'll have to use callback for processing to use in two places.

Answer (score 0):

The [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event is firing when the `<input>`s *value* is changed. The *value* is updated when the `<input>` loses focus. You could add a [`blur()`](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) handler to intercept the "change".

Comment: Mate. I don't need to trigger change at all, no matter what. I need to do it manually after some processing. The problem is, that it triggers the change even before keydown when Enter key is pressed.